# Weird IE Refresh Problem on ASP.Net 3.5 site

Tags: asp.net

I have a very unusual problem that actually took me quite some time to even locate the root cause. I have an ASP.Net 3.5 web application running on Windows Server 2003. I was getting reports from users that said every so often the application would refresh on its own, without user interaction. This was unusual as I have not coded any client side refreshes. After much troubleshooting I narrowed this down to an issue with Internet Explorer (both 7 & 8). FF, Chrome, and Opera do not exhibit this behavior.

Basically, this only happens the first time a user visits the site on a new instance of IE (either a new window or new tab). If the user goes to any page within the site, and then does not interact with the site again, after 6 minutes the browser refreshes! After that refresh, as long as it is the same instance of IE, no matter what page on the site you visit, and no matter how long you let it sit, you never see the refresh again. This has really baffled me, and has become a major problem as this app has data entry forms that take longer than 6 minutes to complete. Unfortunately, if the user gets caught by this refresh bug, anything they entered is lost because of the post.

I need help!! Any advice or options to try would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

(no, I cannot require them to use a better browser as this is a corporate environment with restrictions set to use IE for non-technical users)

Answer (score 1):

It's a stretch, but maybe you have a 3rd party component that's adding a meta refresh tag only for IE (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp (refresh value)). Or maybe there is client-side code generated somewhere only in the case of IE that puts a location.reload() or location.href = someLocation a client-side script block in your markup.

Have you compared the HTML markup in IE and and FireFox? Are they the same? That's where I would start. If they end up being the same, look at script references and search for location.reload() or location.href.

And actually maybe before that, run IE without Add Ons enabled and see if it refreshes. To run without addons, do this at the command line, "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"  -extoff

Comment: Source code between browsers is the same. I have tested on 12 different machines, XP and Vista, on IE7 or 8, and all behave the same. No add-ins either. I checked to make sure that there was no reload or refresh code, and there is not. This would also seem to be supported by the fact that this only happens on the initial page visit of the initial instance of IE. I can navigate away from the site to other sites and come back and it does not exhibit this refresh behavor.

Comment: Maybe load up Fiddler, http://www.fiddlertool.com, and see what's going on. Also, do you have any AJAX on this page? Maybe an UpdatePanel is causing a non-asynch postback in IE only... once again a stretch.

Comment: What am I looking for in Fiddler? This isn't happening on just one particular page, it is happening to the entire application, no matter what page the user is on. Some pages have AJAX, some do not. It happens in both cases.

Comment: I suggested Fiddler because maybe there is stuff in the header or response that is causing the refresh when IE7/IE8 renders the page. In fact maybe compare the Fiddler response from IE and FireFox and see where they differ. If they are the same then there has to be a script reference or client-side script that is causing the issue. I know I asked this before, but have you looked at all the script references (includes *.axd files) and are 100% positive there is no redirect or page refresh client-side code? If still no luck, you should post a link to the live site if possible or some code.